# Loops mixed alphabet and number to have 3 characters string

Tags: php

I would like to loop alphabet and number in sequence to have 3 characters string until the result is true.
The sequence should be A00, A01....A99, B00, B01....Z99 then AA1, AA2...and the last is ZZ9

I tried using this; it's able to generate A01 to Z99

```
$success = false;
foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $x)
{
    if ($success === false)
    {
        for ($y = 0;$y < 100;$y++)
        {
            if ($success === false)
            {
                $serialNo = $x . sprintf("%02d", $y);
                
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using this, I managed to get AA9 to ZZ9

```
$success = false;
foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $x)
{
    if ($success === false)
    {
        foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $y)
        {

            for ($z = 0;$z < 10;$z++)
            {
                if ($success === false)
                {
                    $serialNo =  $x . $y . $z;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

If I just want to start the looping from a certain position,  for example start from A99 or BB1, how can I do this? This is because I need to send the serialNo to a shared API which I don't know the last increment.

Comment: what does the $success === false is doing here? the condition will always be true.
also , are you trying to populate an array with this data or you are trying to create a string?

Comment: actually $success is the result from the API. if the API return is true, then break the loop else keep loop until the serialNo is valid to be inserted. Sorry for missing the API code in my question.

Comment: Instead of loops in loops in loops, you should rather be treating this like a math problem - if I asked you what number comes after 645, then you would probably be able to answer that, without much "looping", right? And you also know, if that last digit was already a `9`, then it would have to become a `0`, and we would have to "carry the one" over to the next higher digit ... Pretty much same principle here, only that your "digits" don't just go from 0 to 9 in some places, but from 0 to 9 and then from A to Z.

Answer (score 1):

Example start from BB1.

`foreach (range('B', 'Z') as $x)`

`foreach (range('B', 'Z') as $y)`

`for ($z = 1;$z < 10;$z++)`

You simply to modify the start of the range to the character you are starting from.